How to enable Bluetooth on the Raspberry Pi 3B with Void Linux?
I have a RPI 3B with Void Linux, I've searched a lot on Google how to enable Bluetooth, but I can't find solutions.... Here are the things I have already done:
Followed to the letter the indications https://docs.voidlinux.org/config/bluetooth.html
I have already added the line dtparam=krnbt=on In /boot/config.txt
Rfkill shows the following:
$ rfkill
ID TYPE DEVICE SOFT HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0 unlocked unlocked unlocked
 1 wlan phy0 unlocked phy0 unlocked unlocked

Dmesg shows:
sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
Password: 
[ 4.036991] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[4.037094] NET: PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family registered
[4.037099] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[4.037119] Bluetooth: HCI Socket Layer Initialized
[4.037126] Bluetooth: L2CAP Socket Layer Initialized
[4.037140] Bluetooth: SCO Socket Layer Initialized
[5.262545] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[5.262572] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[5.263061] Bluetooth: HCI UART Three-wire (H5) protocol registered
[5.263329] Bluetooth: HCI UART Broadcom protocol registered
[7.520967] Bluetooth: hci0: 0xfc18 tx timeout command
[ 15.585064] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: failed to write baudrate update (-110)
[ 15.585227] Bluetooth: hci0: Failure to set baudrate
[16.259899] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[16.259921] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: Multicast Protocol
[16.259941] Bluetooth: BNEP Socket Layer Initialized
[ 17.600974] Bluetooth: hci0: 0x0c03 tx timeout command
[ 25.824953] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reset failed (-110)

I have installed Blueman-manager too, and it shows this when I tried to open in terminal:
$ sudo blueman-manager
Contraseña: 
blueman-manager 23.07.59 ERROR    Manager:147 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.
blueman-manager 23.07.59 ERROR    Manager:151 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting

List of my enabled services:
ls /var/service
agetty-tty1  agetty-tty5     bluetoothd  dhcpcd        ntpd   udevd
agetty-tty2  agetty-tty6     cronie      elogind       rngd   wpa_supplicant
agetty-tty3  agetty-ttyAMA0  cupsd       fake-hwclock  saned  zramen
agetty-tty4  alsa            dbus        lxdm          sshd

cdmline.txt:
snd_bcm2835.enable_headphones=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 root=PARTUUID=3b479547-02 rw rootwait console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 smsc95xx.turbo_mode=N dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 loglevel=4 elevator=noop 

And I have added the group bluetooth to my user...
What can I do more? Any help will be appreciated!
PD: If you ask me, WiFi is working perfectly...

Have  you tried sudo bluetoothctl power on ?

@StephenHarris Yes, it says: 'No default controller available'
